# How can I host HTML5 in my .NET application?

Tags: .net, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-frame

How can I host HTML5 in my .NET application?

Is there a WebKit control? Or a Chronium Control? Can I host the [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) inside the IE web control?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [WebKit .NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) or [Mono's WebBrowser](http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser).

Comment: Thanks. Does it work? Is it kept up to date with the most recent version of webkit?

Comment: I have no idea; I've never used it.

Comment: Mono one looks really neat--supports both Gecko and WebKit rendering engines through same API.

Answer (score 1):

No to Google Chrome frame.

> **Does Google Chrome Frame support .NET WebBrowser, Maxthon, and similar browsers?**
>
> No. Google Chrome Frame is an Active Document Server that hosts web pages rendered using Google Chrome's rendering engine, just as Internet Explorer uses its rendering engine, Mshtml.dll (Trident). Google Chrome Frame is designed to work only inside Internet Explorer and not with other browsers that embed Mshtml.dll, such as Maxthon.

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/faq.html#does_gcf_support